# Change a way fixtures are called in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am having a fixture in conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
@pytest.mark.usefixtures
def pause_on_assert():
    yield
    if hasattr(sys, 'last_value') and isinstance(sys.last_value, AssertionError):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(sys.last_value)
```

Similarly there are many other fixures in the conftest.py with scope as `session`, `module`

My test cases looks like this

`test.py`

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def _wrapper:
    print("pre condition")
    yield
    print("post condition")

def test_abc():
    assert 1==0
```

Problem is I want my fixture that is there in conftest.py to run before `yield` of fixture that is in my testcase

How can i change order in the way fixture are executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure a piece of code runs after the test function, but before all fixtures teardown, I'd advise to use the [`pytest_runtest_teardown`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_teardown) hook instead. Replace the `pause_on_assert` fixture in your `conftest.py` with:

```
def pytest_runtest_teardown(item, nextitem):
    if hasattr(sys, 'last_value') and isinstance(sys.last_value, AssertionError):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(sys.last_value)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of running my conftest.py function that prints "A" before my test function that prints "B".

cd to the parent directory, for this example it is py_tests and run.

```
pytest -s -v
```

The output is:

```
A
setting up
B
PASSED
```

---

With directory structure:

```
py_tests
 -conftest.py
 -tests
  --tests.py
```

---

Files:

```
conftest.py
```

---

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def print_one():
    print("\n")
    print("A")
```

---

```
test.py
```

---

```
import pytest

class Testonething:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
    def setup(self, print_one):
        print("setting up")

    def test_one_thing(self):
        print("B")
        assert True
```

Comment: You are not using autouse=True in test.py fixture.

Comment: @ Nitesh for the the purpose of executing a conftest.py fixture function before a test function adding autouse=True makes no difference. Adding autouse=True to my example will not change the output.

Comment: @Nitesh the example has been edited to take advantage of autouse=True. This specific intent was not stated in the original question. See the updated example. Additional information can be found in the documentation. Here 
https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/fixture.html

Answer (score 2):

Since your `_wrapper` is a function-scoped autouse fixture: it will be instantiated before other fixtures within the same scope. So, hot fix is to define `_wrapper` without `autouse=True` and try to call that decorator implicitly like:

```py
def test_abc(_wrapper):
    assert 1==0
```

[Autouse source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#order-higher-scoped-fixtures-are-instantiated-first)

[Update] If you don't have an ability to change your test suites,  I suggest you just wipe all local specific `_wrapper` and refactor your conftest-specified fixture to call `_wrapper`, because fixture functions can use other fixtures themselves. Your `conftest.py` will be look like this:

```py
# conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def _wrapper(pause_on_assert):
    print("pre condition")
    yield
    print("post condition")

@pytest.fixture()
def pause_on_assert():
    yield
    if hasattr(sys, 'last_value') and isinstance(sys.last_value, AssertionError):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(sys.last_value)
```

[Modularity source](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#modularity-using-fixtures-from-a-fixture-function)

Comment: Is there any other way of doing that. I cannot make this change as there as 1000 testcases

Comment: @Nitesh Do you try to relocate `_wrapper` to the `conftest.py` as is?

Comment: I should be more specific. I have number of classes.  Each class contain methods and each method is a testcase for me. There are n number of classes currently and each class is having a fixture wth same name _wrapper  but its different for each class. So I cannot move this wrapper in conftest.py

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read your answer but this does not fit in my requirement although I may use this in future for other problems. As I said, _wrapper function for every class have different conditions. Name is same but fixture definition is different. Your answer says to mave _wrapper to conftest and use pause on assert in that fixture. Let me know If this is not what you have intended to write.

Comment: @Nitesh because `pause_on_assert` has not defined with `autouse=True` and not implicitly calls by the test_case the order of fixtures will be as you need. Anyway if you have any dependencies in the scope of each test case for the `_wrapped`-like you need refactoring.